# how do i can write regular expression for URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im going to use regular expression for get some section of my URL.

I have these two URLs.

```
http://site/post/post-link

http://site/post/post-link/
```

I can use below code for get `post-link` from 1st URL.

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But above code has issue with `/` in 2nd URL , cant work properly.

So, Im tend to mind, ask:

1.How do i solve that issue with my code

2.Have you any idea for write better code than mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(.*)` is known as a *greedy match* and you are matching everything up to the end of the string `$`. Make it non-greedy with `(.*?)`  After it, add `/?` for an optionally matched `/` which is *not* captured from `()` into `$1`:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*?)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Note that since `.*` matches *zero* or more of any characters, your rule will also match `/post/` with no title after it. If that should not happen, and an empty title should not be sent to `index.php`., use `(.+?)` to require *at least one* character instead of `(.*?)`.

Even better is to use `([^/]+)` which matches everything up to but not including the next `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: But your regex will capture `post-link/` instead of `post-link` because of optinal slash at the end. So you have to make `.*` ungreedy.